# Permanently remove an environment variable

Tags: ubuntu, bash, java, environment-variables

While installing Android Studio, it installed Jayatana as a dependency. Now when I ran java, it showed me a message as: `Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -javaagent:/usr/share/java/jayatanaag.jar`

I uninstalled the jayatana package, but the message didn't disappear. So I unset the environment variable using `unset JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` but this only stays for a bash session. If I close and reopen the shell, the variable is back. I have looked into the .bashrc, .profile, /etc/profile, /etc/bash.bashrc files and I couldn't find this variable defined anywhere.

Is there a way to permanently unset this environment variable? Or to find where it is defined?

Comment: How did you install and remove `jayatana`?  If you did it using `apt-get` it should have removed anything it installed, but if there is a bug in the package, you may need to `apt-get remove --purge jayatana` -- if that helps, file a bug against the package.

Comment: @tripleee I did not install jayatana. It got installed along with Android Studio by Ubuntu Make. I did not purge it while removal, but the package did uninstall successfully. I just needed to log out and back in for the unset command to show permanent change, as I discovered later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find which file defines `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS`, run this:

```
PS4='+ $BASH_SOURCE:$LINENO:' BASH_XTRACEFD=7 bash -xlic ""  7>trace.out
```

The above command turns on diagnostics and saves the diagnostic output to `trace.out`.  (For an explanation of how it works, [click here](https://askubuntu.com/a/591723/221266).)  When the command is done, run:

```
grep JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS trace.out
```

This will show you which file defines `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` and the line number in that file which does it.